# jquery how to keep settings after page reload using filtrify plugin?

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-plugins, browser-cache

First of all I would like to say that I have done my homework. I understand that javascript isn't supposed to keep it's settings after page reload.

I also found 3 ways how this could be done:
1. Cookies
2. html local storage
3. Ajax

After trying to achieve this using html local storage, for several days, I've given up. I found this tutorial, which allows to cache whole html interface - [see "Caching a whole interface"](http://24ways.org/2010/html5-local-storage/). I made some progress using this method, but ultimately I failed.

This is my [filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/) code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var container = $("#itemListLeading"),
        pagination = $("#pagination");

    function setLazyLoad () {
        container.find("img").lazyload({
            event : "turnPage",
            effect : "fadeIn"
        });
    };

    function setPagination () {
        pagination.jPages({
            containerID : "itemListLeading",
            perPage : 9,
            direction : "auto",
            animation : "fadeInUp",
            previous  : "a.jprev",
            next      : "a.jnext",
            callback : function( pages, items ){
                items.showing.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
                items.oncoming.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
            }
        });
    };

    function destroyPagination () {
        pagination.jPages("destroy");
    };



    setLazyLoad();
    setPagination();

    var ft = $.filtrify("itemListLeading", "placeHolder", {
        close: true, // Close windows after tag select
        block : "data-original",
        callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {

            if ( mismatch.length ) $("div#reset").show(); // Show Reset
            else $("div#reset").hide();

            $('.ft-label').parent() // Hide unrelated tags
                .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
                .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();

            $(".ft-selected li").css("display","inline-block"); // small tag display fix

            destroyPagination();
            setPagination();

        }
    });

    $("div#reset span").click(function() { // Make reset button clickable
        ft.reset();
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

This was my shot at local storage implementation:

```
 $(function() {
  var edit = document.getElementById('filter-menu');
  $(edit).blur(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.innerHTML);
        });

  // when the page loads
  if ( localStorage.getItem('todoData') ) {
        edit.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todoData');
        }

  $("#reset span").click(function() { // Reset cache button
      localStorage.clear();
      location.reload();
  });   
});
```

Problems I experienced:
1.Cache didn't always work (I got better result using .click function)
2.When cache did work it cached state of filter settings(pressed butons), but all filter objects were displayed (instead of just those related to filter settings)
3.I couldn't reset cache (reload worked) using reset button (last paragraph of code), although when I copied `localStorage.clear(); location.reload();` in firebug console cache got reset.

Comment: +1 for showing some effort and formatting

Answer (score 1):

Within your filtrify callback function you need to save the `query` as a string to e.g. local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('ftquery', JSON.stringify(query))
```

Then after you instantiate filtrify you need to 'trigger' the query

```
ft.trigger(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ftquery')));
```

So, to use your code example, edit the filtrify section like so:

```
var ft = $.filtrify("itemListLeading", "placeHolder", {
    close: true, // Close windows after tag select
    block : "data-original",
    callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {

        // save query to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('ftquery', JSON.stringify(query));

        ...

    }
});

// retrieve query from localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem('ftquery')) {
    ft.trigger(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ftquery')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're dead set on a javascript solution, and you are in fact using jQuery, I'd consider taking a look at the jQuery Cookie Plugin ( https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie ). It's perfect for situations like this and might inspire you investigate cookies further, with say php.

If you decided to take this route, the implementation would be straight forward. You'd handle it in a similar fashion as localStorage:

```
$(function() {
     var edit = document.getElementById('filter-menu').innerHTML;   
     $.cookie('todoData', edit, { expires: 7 });
});
```

I've used this to implement a similar feature set, and I believe it's handled well across most modern browsers. I'd also recommend being a little more specific grabbing each tag, perhaps loop through each list item (LI), and separate with commas.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I still can't make this work with my site
`$(document).ready(function() {
     var edit = document.getElementById('filter-menu').innerHTML; 
  
  $('#filter-menu').blur(function() {  
      $.cookie('todoData', edit, { expires: 7 });
  });
});`

I added `$(document).ready(function() {` because menu is generated by jquery filtrify plugin.

I added `blur(function() {` so that caching would begin when ul of filter loses it's forucs.